# Visual Studio 2010 modeling project error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, uml

I have serious problem with my modeling project, created in Visual Studio 2010. Today I was renaming my project and solution name and path's. And now it throws me some kind of error, when I wish to open any diagram. And then i role everything back to the first settings, but still the same.

Error:

> Cannot load
>
> 'C:\Users\Klemen\Trgovina\Knjiznica\UMLUseCaseDiagram1.
>
> usecasediagram': You must open this UML diagram inside the Visual
>
> Studio modeling project that was used to create it.

Does anyone know, how to make my project work again?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any Add-On/Plugin ? I had a conflicting add-on and after removing it, it is working again.